citus cluster is locked
We have citus cluster with pg_autofailover.
Something strange was happened and the cluster collapsed.
We are trying to fix the cluster.
I see that pg_dist_node is different on the coordinator and worker nodes and pg_dist_node is locked exclusively on the coordinator and this locker record has no pid.
I can not kill locker process because it has no pid and I can not do anything else because pg_dist_node is locked.
I will be glad for any advice.
